# How to extend CodedUI HtmlControls and preserve typing

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion, coded-ui-tests

I've been digging into CodedUI heavily recently and have been having fun extending the library to include the rest of the HTML elements that (for whatever reason) were left out of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls namespace.

I've noticed that I can do things like:

```
var divs = new HtmlDiv(window).FindMatchingControls().OfType<HtmlDiv>();
```

and this will return what you expect: an IEnumerable with the same elements as the FindMatchingControls() call (just typed as HtmlDiv instead of UITestControl).

Also, I can do this:

```
public class HtmlHeader : HtmlCustom
{
    public static readonly string HeaderTag = "header";

    public HtmlHeader() : base() {
 this.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, HeaderTag, PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
    }
    public HtmlHeader(UITestControl parent) : base(parent) { 
     this.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.TagName, HeaderTag, PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
    }
}
```

and even this works:

```
var headerTag = new HeaderTag(window);
```

it will find the header tags on the screen and get the first one for you.

```
var headerTags = new HeaderTag(window).FindMatchingControls();
```

works fine, but

```
var headerTags = new HeaderTag(window).FindMatchingControls().OfType<HeaderTag>();
```

is empty.

Why do the HtmlControls in the above namespace properly resolve types?

Would I be able to utilize an implicit conversion operator / some other trick to get OfType() to return a collection of HtmlTags?

I started writing a conversion like:

```
protected HeaderTag ConvertControl(HtmlControl toConvert)
    {
        if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase(toConvert.TagName, "header"))
        {
            var ret = new HeaderTag();
            ret.SearchProperties.AddRange(toConvert.SearchProperties);
            ret.SearchConfigurations = toConvert.SearchConfigurations;
            ret.FilterProperties.AddRange(toConvert.FilterProperties);
            // screen element
            // technology is already set - web
            // cached queryid
            // cached parent
            // boundary screen element
            return ret;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Control cannot be converted.");
    }
```

However, after decompiling the HtmlControl type itself, I saw there is a CopyFromControl method which is not accessible; further, the fields it is setting are inaccessible (commented above).

I'm not sure if it really matters whether I copy those fields and if they are overly important to copy or not, but I'm hoping to find a better solution.  If nothing better comes up, I'll probably resort to reflection, but I'd rather not go that route if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITestControl is basicly just a wrapper to access the native UI controls. Once a UI control is found the UITestControl keeps a reference to that object. Then you can use its CopyFrom function to copy that reference (along with search properties).

So instead of converting or casting you could (and probably should) simply call the CopyFrom function on an instance of your own class, passing it the UITestControl returned by FindMatchingControls.

I'm not nifty enough with Linq so the code is not pretty, but something like this would work:

```
List<HeaderTag> list = new List<HeaderTag>();
foreach (var item in new HeaderTag(window).FindMatchingControls())
{
    HeaderTag temp = new HeaderTag();
    temp.CopyFrom(item);
    list.Add(temp);
}
```

I'm not sure why casting doesn't since your class is derived from UITestControl. But if casting fails you should use CopyFrom.

Comment: ugh, I feel stupid.  I was recreating the CopyFrom method which I thought was private for some reason @_o